# Issue downloading audio with ytdlp on a raspberry pi

Tags: encoding, raspberry-pi, discord.py, byte

I recently moved my discord bot from replit to my raspberry pi. My discord bot was able to use ytdlp to extract audio from youtube queries. The command to download youtube audio worked perfectly fine on replit, however on the raspberry pi I get the error

`a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

the error is with the following command.

```
    @app_commands.command(
            name="downloadyoutubeaudio",
            description="Download youtube audio as an mp3 (Takes a few seconds)")
    @app_commands.describe(youtubevideo="The youtube url or search terms")
    async def youtubedownload(self, interaction: discord.Interaction,
                                                        youtubevideo: str):

        await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=False)
        loop2 = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        try:

            audiodata = await loop2.run_in_executor(
                    None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(youtubevideo, download=True))

            audiofilename = audiodata['title'] + '.mp3'
            await interaction.followup.send(
                    file=discord.File('youtubemp3.mp3', filename=audiofilename))

            os.remove('youtubemp3.mp3')
```

specifically this line

`audiodata = await loop2.run_in_executor( None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(youtubevideo, download=True))`

Online people have said  use the `.encode()` method however when I use it I get the error
`cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`
These two errors seem to contradict. I believe the error is in how my raspberry pi encodes bytes but I do not know how to fix it.

Edit:

When printing the type of youtubevideo, I do get string.

The full error is below

```
Command 'downloadyoutubeaudio' raised an exception: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='CommandTree-invoker' coro=<CommandTree._from_interaction.<locals>.wrapper() done, defined at /home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py:1087> exception=CommandInvokeError("Command 'downloadyoutubeaudio' raised an exception: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 827, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(self.binding, interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/Desktop/code/musiccommands.py", line 319, in youtubedownload
    raise e
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/Desktop/code/musiccommands.py", line 302, in youtubedownload
    audiodata = await loop2.run_in_executor(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/Desktop/code/musiccommands.py", line 303, in <lambda>
    None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(video, download=True))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1594, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, self.get_info_extractor(key), download, extra_info, process)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1605, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1761, in __extract_info
    return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1840, in process_ie_result
    return self.extract_info(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1594, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, self.get_info_extractor(key), download, extra_info, process)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1605, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1761, in __extract_info
    return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1890, in process_ie_result
    return self.__process_playlist(ie_result, download)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1981, in __process_playlist
    'playlist', ie_result, self.prepare_filename(ie_copy, 'pl_infojson'))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1437, in prepare_filename
    filename = self._prepare_filename(info_dict, tmpl_type=dir_type, outtmpl=outtmpl)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1407, in _prepare_filename
    outtmpl = self._outtmpl_expandpath(outtmpl)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1139, in _outtmpl_expandpath
    outtmpl = outtmpl.replace('%%', f'%{sep}%').replace('$$', f'${sep}$')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1091, in wrapper
    await self._dispatch_error(interaction, e)
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1084, in _dispatch_error
    await self.on_error(interaction, error)
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/Desktop/code/main.py", line 551, in on_app_command_error
    raise error
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1089, in wrapper
    await self._call(interaction)
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1252, in _call
    await self.on_error(interaction, e)
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/Desktop/code/main.py", line 551, in on_app_command_error
    raise error
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/SamuelDorfman/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'downloadyoutubeaudio' raised an exception: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

EDIT:
I just fixed the issue.
The problem was with my outtmpl options. Setting
`'outtmpl':'youtubemp3.%(ext)s'` fixed the issue

Comment: If you print the type of `youtubevideo` (param) then does it print string? Also, can we get the full stack trace?

Comment: @BlueRobin It does print that the type is a string. I have just updated the post with the full stack trace.